# How do I identify control center elements in Xcode UI tests?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I managed to open the control center of the device, but i cannot identify the buttons, I need the Wi-Fi one more exactly. I tried with the recorder and it's identified as

app.scrollViews.otherElements.scrollViews.otherElements.switches["Wi-Fi"]

but when I try to run the test again, it fails as it does not find the element. 
I also tried to find it as other kind of element(buttons or all kinds of bars elements), but nothing works. Also tried to identify it by its label simply using app.buttons["Wi-Fi"] and still no results.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried using the Identity Inspector to inspect the WiFi button?

Comment: Maybe you need to wait for the item to appear first. It's possible that your test is trying to check on its existence before it is shown on the screen. http://masilotti.com/xctest-helpers/

Comment: @Frederik with the inspector and i got that the element is a button labeled as "Wi-Fi"

Comment: @Hodson I tried a wait method from Masilotti's blog, but the element does not get identified. I have the same problem with permission alerts. Maybe because they are not descendants of the app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The control centre is outside the scope of your application under test and therefore cannot be accessed by your UI tests.

To disable wifi, you need to physically disconnect the device from the Internet, as it's not possible to disconnect from wifi programmatically.

Comment: i managed to interact with the mail app that is launched to send feedback for example, that's why i thought it would make sense to work for control center as well. Is that treated differently?

Comment: When you have your app open an email, it is a stripped down version of an email, as it's embedded in your app. If your app were to link out to the full Mail app, you wouldn't be able to interact with it. :)

Comment: I understand :) I'll close the question. Any other idea how to manage the wifi connection from the tests?

Comment: There may be something to toggle the wifi reachability in the `simctl` tool but I don't think it would be plausible to sync it up with your tests to change the wifi status mid-test. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 9 the Control Center is now accessible (the Springboard controls it). Right now it is only possible on a physical device because the Xcode 9 beta simulators don't have a control center. Maybe that will be fixed when Xcode is officially released. For now you have to use a real device.

This test opens the control center and taps on the WiFi Button:

```
func testSwitchOffWiFi() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")

    app.launch()

    // open control center
    let coord1 = app.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.99))
    let coord2 = app.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.5))
    coord1.press(forDuration: 0.1, thenDragTo: coord2)

    let wifiButton = springboard.switches["wifi-button"]
    wifiButton.tap()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's rather easy done using the setting app...

- First you know if the airplane mode icon is present if you query the taskbar.

`XCUIElement* airplaneModeIcon = app.windows.otherElements[@"Airplane mode on"];
 const bool isAirplaneModeEnabled = airplaneModeIcon.exists;`

- If after that you realize that you really need to set airplane mode to on or off, you need to launch the settings app.

`XCUIApplication* settings = [[XCUIApplication alloc] initWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Preferences"];

[settings launch];

XCUIElement* airplaneModeCell = settings.tables.cells[@"Airplane Mode"];
// Do what you have to do with the Cell...`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an adaptation of joern's answer for iPhones with notch. Also, we don't need to refer to the app under test at all - springboard is enough.

```swift
func toggleWiFi() {
  let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier:"com.apple.springboard")
    
  // expand control center
  let start = springboard.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.9, dy: 0.01))
  let end = springboard.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.9, dy: 0.2))
  start.press(forDuration: 0.1, thenDragTo: end)
   
  // perform the action
  let wifiButton = springboard.switches["wifi-button"]
  wifiButton.tap()
    
  // hide control center
  let empty = springboard.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.9, dy: 0.1))
  empty.tap()
  }
}
```